# Using font awsome icons with css modules

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, jsx, css-modules

I want to use a font awsome icon together with css modules. Since they have "static selectors", I'm not sure how to accomplish this. F.e:

```
<i
  className={styles.icon} 
>
Hi
</i>
```

Now i want to add the icon with `"fas fa-search fa-2x"`.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: why not just use `<i calssName="fas fa-search fa-2x">Hi</i>`. What's the issue in using that

Comment: Well, for the rest of my codebase I'm using css modules and in the exact case, there is a lot of styling to the <i> </i> tag so I have to give them a class. Otherwise these styles would apply globally which is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine css-modules based classes and fontawesome classes

```
<i calssName={`${styles.icon} fas fa-search fa-2x`}>Hi</i>
```

where `styles.icon` is custom styling for this icon

Comment: Do you want a different approach?